# How to solve the content re-locating problems that happen when screen size is reduced?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently on a project to make a website for piano selling and I have come across some problems. First, when the screen size is reduced, my nav lists wrap themselves in a column direction which makes it look really ugly. I want them not to wrap themselves but just keep their place even when the screen size is reduced. Secondly, also when the screen size is reduced, contents in  go out of the box. How can I solve these problems?

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Birdlove";
    src: url(./font-face/Birdlove.ttf) format('truetype');
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 75px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.container-background-image{
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
}

span.home {
    font-size: 74px;
    font-family: 'Cormorant SC', serif;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

span a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: seashell;
}

header {
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

header img {
    height: 80%;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

nav {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

nav ul {
    text-align: right;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav a.even:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: ease-out 0.5s;
}


nav a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 30px 20px;
}

.search {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.search img {
    height: 40px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.mission {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.mission-text {
    padding: 200px 100px 0 100px;
}

.mission-text p {
    width: 638px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.mission .btn-more {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.mission .btn-more a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 white;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.mission .btn-more a:hover {
    color: black;
    box-shadow: inset 150px 0 0 0 white;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.products {
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.products h1 {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Shippori Mincho', serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

.products h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.products .image-background h2{
    background-image: url("./img/img-piano-small.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 39.5% 0;
    margin: 0 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
    color: white;
    transition: ease-in 0.3s;
}

.products .image-background h2:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.image-gallery {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.products .image {
    width: 23%;
    height: 22%;
}

.image img {
    width: 90%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.people {
    height: 100vh;
}

.people h1 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@700&family=Quattrocento+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+SC:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quattrocento+Sans:wght@700&family=Shippori+Mincho:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-background-image">
      <header>
        <span class="home"><a href="#">Virtuoso</a></span>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="odd" href="#">Virtuoso</a></li>
            <li><a class="even" href="#">Mission</a></li>
            <li><a class="odd" href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a class="even" href="#">People</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="search">
          <form action="">
            <input type="text" value="search">
          </form>
          <img src="./img/iconfinder_icon-111-search_314807.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="mission">
        <div class="mission-text">
          <h1>The Best Piano Collections.</h1>
          <p>Steinway & Sons, YAMAHA, FAZIOLI, KAWAI etc.</p>
          <div class="btn-more">
            <a href="#">See More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="products">
      <h1>Products.</h1>
      <div class="image-gallery">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="./img/img-piano-small.jpg" alt=""><h2>Steinway & Sons</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <img src="./img/img-piano-small.jpg" alt=""><h2>YAMAHA</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="image image-background">
          <h2>FAZIOLI</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="image image-background">
          <h2>KAWAI</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="people">
      <h1>Our Team.</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
nav {
    overlow: hidden
}  

nav a: {
    display: block, horizontal;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 30px 20px;
}
```

Try this one for navigation bar.

For the content, i would suggest below. In head of your document you can type :

```
<meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And CSS

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, <meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> this does not work in my laptop I don't know why..